# Can't boot into Ubuntu; Can't Install Grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

yo. Today I installed EndeavourOS (HOLD ONTO YOUR HAT; THIS QUESTION IS ABOUT UBUNTU DON'T BAN IT), and whenever I tried starting my computer it booted into the EndeavourOS Bootloader (Grub, but different background). From there I couldn't start ubuntu. I wanted to go back to Ubuntu, so I inserted my Live USB, and deleted the partition with Endeavour Os, thinking everything would be fine, but NO. I tried restarting, and it entered Grub Rescue mode. Then I booted into my Live USB again and tried using Boot repair. Following Error:

`The current session is in BIOS-compatibility mode. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB) that is compatible with UEFI booting mode. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode. This will enable this feature.`

Then I tried using [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1317945/1664901) answer, to try something else. I ran:
`mount /dev/sda6 /mnt`>>
`mount: /mnt: must be superuser to use mount.`
and then I did `sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt`>>
sudo: unable to allocate pty: No such device`

I tried some other stuff, but nothing worked. I couldn't find a solution to the first error, or to the second one.
Can anybody help me? Please. I wanna finish my homework.

Comment: You need to boot Ubuntu live installer or Boot-Repair in UEFI boot mode, not old BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. You should have both as selection depending on how you make live install flash drive. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!
You have to boot into a Live USB, and install it. It will create another Ubuntu Install, and then there will be "Operating systems detected: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS". Then install along side them, and the problem is fixed!

Comment: That just caused a new `grub` to be installed with it detecting your other OS.  There is a command `grub-install` which if run on Ubuntu before you'd removed the other non-Ubuntu OS, would have ensured Ubuntu owned the boot process & your delete of partition(s) wouldn't have matters (*Windows & all OSes have such a command for this*).   You could have fixed it from *live* media or via Boot-Repair as per OldFred's advice.  But well done on getting around the issue !